# How can I sort multiple mysql foreach arrays and need them in consistent in php?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, sorting

I am trying to sort the mysql data by my calculated value. I know rsort(), sort(), however, I cannot sort them individual outside the foreach because it will not be consistent. I have three arrays need to be in consistent when I only want to sort them by the percentage. How can I do that? Appreciate.

```
<?php
   //certain mysql connection code hide because it's not relative to this question.
     foreach ($rows as row) {
    $member_id=row['user_id'];
    $count=row['count'];

    $user_link[]=bp_core_get_user_domain( $member_id );
    $user_displayname[]=bp_core_get_user_displayname( $member_id );

    $combine_count[]=round(($count/$count_user_diff)*100);//calculate value

   }//foreach
   //how can I sort data here since I have three arrays together.
for ($i=0; $i<7; $i++){
echo "<a href='$user_link[$i]'><div>$user_avatar[$i]<ul>$combine_count[$i]</ul></div></a>";
}

?>
```

Comment: Sort the first, get the list of keys from that, then use array_multisort() to sort the other two arrays based on that set of keys

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to maintain a connection between the three array is to use associative arrays. If the member id is unique, then use it for the index of each array. For example:

```
<?php

  // $unique_id = 0; // in case $member_id is not unique
  foreach ($rows as $row) {
    $member_id = $row['user_id'];
    $count = $row['count'];

    // use $member_id as index to align arrays
    $user_link[$member_id]=bp_core_get_user_domain( $member_id );
    $user_displayname[$member_id]=bp_core_get_user_displayname( $member_id );
    //$user_avatar[$member_id]=bp_core_get_user_avatar( $member_id ); // missing avatar array?

    $combine_count[$member_id]=round(($count/$count_user_diff)*100);
    //$unique_id++;
  }

  arsort($combine_count); // maintain index, descending order
  // $combine_count = array_slice($combine_count, 0, 7, true); // top 7
  // slice array if you only want the top 7 as the question implies

  // loop over $combine_count array
  foreach ( $combine_count as $member_id => $c_count ) {
    echo "<a href='$user_link[$member_id]'><div>$user_avatar[$member_id]<ul>$combine_count[$member_id]</ul></div></a>";
  }

?>
```

If the member id's can occur multiple times in the result set, then simply instantiate a variable, such as `$unique_id` in the example, and increment it with each result, and use that for the index on all three arrays instead of `$member_id`.

Alternatively, if you want to show only the first few results, and you want to maintain the complete `$combine_count` array for later use, you can also do this:

```
arsort($combine_count); // maintain index, descending order

// loop over $combine_count array
$cc = 0; // start counter
foreach ( $combine_count as $member_id => $c_count ) {
  echo "<a href='$user_link[$member_id]'><div>$user_avatar[$member_id]<ul>$combine_count[$member_id]</ul></div></a>";
  $cc++; // increment counter
  if ( 7 <= $cc ) { break; } // break out of loop if counter is greater than or equal to 7
}
```

Are you missing some `$`s in your code, particularly `row`? I added where I thought they were missing. And it looks like you're missing the `$user_avatar` array. Or am I missing something?

Comment: Thank you very much. Yes, when I paste the code, I might miss those. Although I not quite understand the unique ID part, how magical the member_id inside the array could achieve what I need, it works as I expect. Thanks again. But the slice array didn't work, I don't why. It slice 7 parts. 7 div, but only three div shows data, I fix this part by place a limit in the statement part, but just want to know why slice array doesn't work.Thanks again

Comment: You're welcome. I'm glad you pointed out the problem with `array_slice`. I failed to include the necessary "maintain index" flag as the last parameter to the function. I fixed the example above, and now it slices properly!

Answer (score 1):

Why do you even use three separate arrays? Create one array, which has an associative structure with your three values. Then use [usaort](http://php.net/manual/en/function.uasort.php) to sort your values in whatever order you like.

So, instead of

```
$user_link[]=bp_core_get_user_domain( $member_id );
$user_displayname[]=bp_core_get_user_displayname( $member_id );

$combine_count[]=round(($count/$count_user_diff)*100);//calculate value
```

you use

```
$data[] = array(
            'user_link' => bp_core_get_user_domain( $member_id ),
            'user_displayname' => bp_core_get_user_displayname( $member_id ),
            'combine_count' => round(($count/$count_user_diff)*100)
        );
```

Then use `uasort` on the `$data`. Bonus points if you create a custom Class instead of my associative array.

OR, even a better option: perform everything (calculations, sorting) in your database.

The proof-of-concept code:

```
<pre>
<?php

$data = array();

// Dummy entries
$data[] = array(
    'user_link' => '#',
    'user_displayname' => "Name",
    'combine_count' => 10
);

$data[] = array(
    'user_link' => '#',
    'user_displayname' => "Name",
    'combine_count' => 100
);

$data[] = array(
    'user_link' => '#',
    'user_displayname' => "Name",
    'combine_count' => 40
);

$data[] = array(
    'user_link' => '#',
    'user_displayname' => "Name",
    'combine_count' => 1000
);

// Comparator function
function compare($a, $b) {
    if($a == $b) {
        return 0;
    } else {
        return $a['combine_count'] < $b['combine_count'];
    }
}

// Print (before sorting)
print_r($data);

// Sort
uasort($data, 'compare');

// Print (after sorting)
print_r($data);

?>
</pre>
```

Comment: Thanks for you time. But I am not quiet understand how to separate the user_link from the $data[] and use uasort. If you could provide a example, that would be great. Anyway, still appreciate your help.

Comment: OK, I've updated my answer and provided a proof-of-concept code. Hope it is clear enough.